# Lua-массив кнопок в окне проекта на МТА (клиент)

Tags: lua

Необходимо (на устройстве клиента), в проекте "сервер на `Multi Theft Auto`", вертикально расположить в окне много кнопок.

Проблема в том, что при сохранении кнопок в таблицу, они не появляются.

Работает для одной кнопки:

```
btn1 = guiCreateButton(btnShiftX, btnRegShiftY, btnWidth, btnHeight, "Кнопка", true, windowShopMain)
```

А кнопок нужно сделать некоторое количество.

```
buttons = {}
for i = 0, 7 do
    btnBuff = guiCreateButton(btnShiftX, 20*i+20, btnWidth, btnHeight, "Кнопка", true, windowShopMain)
    table.insert( buttons, btnBuff )
end
```

Такой код не создаёт никаких кнопок. В чём может быть причина? Как исправить?

Comment: Что за среда используется?

Comment: Вы ничего не написали о модуле, который используете для gui - как вам помочь?

Comment: @val, среда - сервер МТА. Клиентская часть. GUI

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch дополнил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что я хотел сдвигать кнопку на 20 единиц. Но эти 20 единиц являлись 2000% от объекта (родителя), так как прототип используемой функции:

> element guiCreateButton ( float x, float y, float width, float height,
>   string text, bool relative, [ element parent = nil ] )

Где `relative` - относительные размеры и расположение. Если это так, то все значения x, y, width и height должны быть в диапазоне от 0 до 1, что соответствует размеру относительно родителя.

По этой причине можно предложить два вида решения:

1. Задать `relative = false` и пересчитать все остальные размеры на абсолютные;
2. Изменить величину смещения.

В общем случае, лучше btnBuff оставить локальной. Предпочтительнее решение второе, потому что оно требует минимальных исправлений:

```
buttons = {}
for i = 0, 7 do
    local btnBuff = guiCreateButton(btnShiftX, 0.1*i+0.1, btnWidth, btnHeight, "Кнопка", true, windowShopMain)
    table.insert( buttons, btnBuff )
end
```

Таким образом, вершины кнопок будут отстоять друг от друга на относительные 10% родителя.

Следует отметить, что в Lua таблицы начинаются не с нулевого индекса, а с первого, из-за чего можно сделать код ещё немного проще и правильнее с точки зрения особенностей Lua:

```
buttons = {}
for i = 1, 8 do
    local btnBuff = guiCreateButton(btnShiftX, 0.1*i, btnWidth, btnHeight, "Кнопка", true, windowShopMain)
    table.insert( buttons, btnBuff )
end
```